# Publishing Office365 Api Webapp in Azure Web site with Azure DB

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api

I am facing strange issue, I'm following this simple (https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-SingleTenant). I follow all steps and Works succesfully in localhost but when I deploy the same app on Microsoft Azure, it throws the following exception Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken. My code runs perfectly against localhost but not on azure. In both cases the App connects to database without problems but there is problems with ADALTokenCache in a Azure Web Site.

I would need steps to publish this sample or similar in a Azure Website and Azure DB. Is possible?

Others samples in office dev like O365-ASPNETMVC-Start or O365-WebApp-MultiTenant have the same problem.

Comment: I believe you might not have activated the ability to "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true (default being "false"), by downloading the Manifest of your app, updating it, and re-uploading it via the Azure portal, Your-domain, Applications > YourApplication selected, in the bottom bar. ALso you need to make sure you have changed the actual ReplyURL to point to the final location of your app, and of course, deliver appropriate "Delegated" permissions, including on the Azure AD

Comment: +1 @C.Marius-MVP please review your app settings on the Azure AD and make sure that the url matches the hosted/deployed site url in addition to the given permissions.